# How to make font of a comments big?

Tags: support

See the comment of @DVK on this question (in desktop view, not mobile): [Is it possible that Dumbledore isn't dead?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75521/is-it-possible-that-dumbledore-isnt-dead)

How to make font size of a comment big? What's the markup?

Can all users do it? Or, only selected guys have this privilege? @DVK in question is topmost guy on SFF.SE and has Gold Badge in *harry-potter* tag. Has something to do with that?

**Update:**
Here's the screenshot as some guys are unable to see it:
[image]

Web Browser is Firefox for Android. I am not using any script or mod.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+scroll? How did it work out?

Comment: @Jan Not funny.

Comment: His comment is not any bigger than any of the other comments...

Comment: No idea what you're asking since his comments are not different than any other comments. Or do you mean he wrote SOME words in ALL CAPS? That's not bigger font, it's called upper case letters.

Comment: @animuson Added the screenshot.

Comment: No-repro on my computer / latest Chrome. What browser, scripts are you using?

Comment: @Shadow Somehow, I am seeing your your comment fonts bigger.

Comment: This is something weird that Android does. It's not a feature of Stack Exchange itself.

Comment: @SachinShekhar something on your end. Try clean browser without extensions/plugin/userscripts and I'm sure you'll see the comments like we all see: same font for all.